What file format was used for binary executables on Motorola 680x0 Macintoshes?
Current macOS binary executable files use a format called "Mach-O" and prior to that there was the PEF "Preferred Object Format", and Wikipedia says "It was optimised for RISC processors".
This makes it seem that it was a new format for the introduction of the PowerPC processor to the Mac. Though perhaps the wording is ambiguous and instead is supposed to suggest that there was an "original" PEF format that was later updated or "optimized".
I can't seem to find anywhere stating what the original file format for Macs was, or if there were several before PEF.

Generally, there is no such thing as a "binary file" in MacOS Classic - There are CODE resources in the resource fork of the application that contain the code segment(s) of the binary, loosely held together by CODE resource 0.
Application runtime structure on the classic Mac is strongly influenced by the capabilities of the early 68k CPUs and by an "everything is floating" (i.e., no fixed memory addresses) paradigm. (Note all of the below describes the mechanisms used in the initial MacOS versions. Apple developed a number of amendments into later versions that fixed some of the limitations of this model - what was later called "the near model", mainly the amount of global data a program could have (32k) and the maximum segment size (32k as well).
The original 68000 can do absolute jumps and calls across the complete 24-bit address range, which would thus obviously need some sort of run-time relocation - And you simply can't use these instructions in a Classic MacOS application.
It can also do register-relative jumps, i.e. look up an address in a table and branch there (these are heavily used, see below).
The CPU can also do PC-relative jumps and branches (i.e. "branch to here + 256 bytes"), but these are limited to +- 32k of range, heavily used as well (this 32k limit was lifted in later CPUs).
These CPU capabilities influence the layout of a MacOS binary into segments - pieces of code, basically limited in size to 32k(*), so everything within a segment is within the range of PC-relative branches, that are stored in separate CODE resources and can be loaded initially or on demand. Code branches within a single CODE resource are strictly PC-relative and statically linked at compile-time. To load a CODE resource, relocation for intra-segment calls is thus not needed.
What follows from this is that applications with only a single CODE resource are limited to 32k code size.
For inter-segment calls and the complete application loading the CODE resource 0 is very important - When loading CODE resources, it generates a jump table from information in the CODE 0 resource and the loaded specific segment, that is always pointed to by a5 and resolves inter-segment address resolution (i.e. calls between segments). Inter-segment calls are always register-relative to a5 (i.e., no further relocation needed), and basically all inter-segment branches have to go across this jump table (identify the "far" routine to be called, look up its load address in the jump table, jump) - a lot like shared library calls in modern operating systems. There is a clever mechanism that allows automatic on-demand loading of CODE resources - A jump into a segment that is currently not loaded will automatically load the respective CODE resource, patch the jump table entry accordingly, and execute the routine. This jumping through a table obviously creates some runtime overhead. On the other hand, jumping through a table allows the operating system to move code segments around at will, even if the application is running, for example in order to compact memory occupation - as long as values in the jump table are adjusted. (BTW: While MacOS supports loading code segments on-demand, it will never unload a segment when it's no longer needed. It will only do so if the developer explicitly says so)
The only relocation information (rather: on-call address fixups) in a MacOS binary is thus contained in the CODE 0 resource that builds this jump table at load time. The other CODE resources for other segments are just statically linked, fully position-independent flat binaries.
(*) Some compilers allowed the creation of bigger code segments by creating so-called "jump islands", series of < 32k-branch instructions spread across the code to split a longer branch into multiple 32k-jumps in order to reach locations further than 32k away. Thus code segments could grow beyond 32k, at the cost of cluttered binaries and runtime overhead.
Classic MacOS is a somewhat weird operating system. Next you would want to look into its dynamic memory management, which operates on handles instead of addresses and is likely to move around your allocated memory at will and without you noticing - invalidating pointers and addresses...
 Some more 2cents: Back in the day, there was a lot of fuss about the superiority of the Motorola CPU architecture above the Intel x86, because it didn't rely on segmentation. Apple managed to artificially introduce segmentation (because that's exactly what CODE resources are - segments of limited size, a size which is even only half of the segment size on an x86 CPU) into Classic MacOS because they didn't want to pay the price for a runtime relocation mechanism - i.e. a "proper" relocation loader, and wanted small, floating entities (i.e. segments :)) in order to be able to squeeze more into the very limited amount of memory early Macs had. Later Macs that had a lot more memory and extended CPUs were rather hampered by these mechanisms
In hindsight, tailoring MacOS so tightly around the 68k CPU made the whole thing very non-portable and likely bit them in the back during PowerPC migration. On the other hand, portability was nowhere a thing in the early 1980s....

Re: handles, it's not that weird. The Win16 API does it that way too. It's basically just an OS-level shim to enable MMU-based RAM defragmentation tricks in 680x0 or x86 CPUs too early to have MMUs. (Alternatively, you can think of it as an OS-level implementation of the compacting part of compacting garbage collection. See "Compacting the Uncompactable" by Bobby Powers for a modern effort to retrofit that into malloc/free without the cooperation of the applications or that "pointer to a table of pointers" element of what handles are.)

On Apple's side of things, given that they controlled the hardware spec, I suspect they had been trained on university UNIX systems that were an order of magnitude or two more expensive and were thinking "How can we get some of that MMU goodness without having to fit an MMU into the bill of materials?"

Worth noting that resources other than CODE could be called by applications.  Some applications had code to custom-render UI controls (CDEF resources), menus (MDEF), and window panes (WDEF).  These had standardized APIs and were automatically loaded and called by the operating system.  However, these were much less common than CODE resources, which contained the "main program".

I used to program in 68000-68040 on Amigas in C and assembly back in the day and wrote my own disassembler. I also had a Mac emulator and I bought System 7.1, CodeWarrior, and several volumes of Inside Macintosh. But I never ended up doing much Mac programming. So I know some stuff and don't find it very weird, but other stuff I don't know or do find weird, or both (-:

@ssokolow apparently the 68451 was quite flawed and required a 68010. Unix 680x0 machines went with their own proprietary MMUs instead. Apple was trying to make the Mac as cheap as possible to produce, especially after the outrageously expensive Lisa.

@ssokolow Don't think they were looking at Unix - They were rather looking at the 68k spec and designed to use that to the fullest to implement a system that could live with a minimum amount of memory on th cheap. (I do think Motorola engineers were looking at Unix, though - so, indirectly, that works out.) And the fact that early Windows did something, doesn't really make anything less weird :)

The key reason for this awkwardness was Apple choosing to only have 128KB with the original Macs, and continuing with that legacy code years later. The Atari ST came with a minimum of 512KB and used a simple flat address model. I don't recall what the Amiga used.

@rcgldr iirc the Amiga also just used a simple flat model. But memory is imperfect now. It's conceivable memory wasn't always contiguous especially with "chip memory" being accessible to the custom chips and therefore slower. I don't remember anything like segments. I didn't mean to imply that Apple was looking at Unix, just that there were other systems that used 680x0 and did have protected memory, and those were Unix Systems. Don't forget A/UX though. I have no idea if it addressed memory protection.

The Amiga uses a similar table mechanism for its shared libraries (a table at the load address of the library and register-relative jumps into the library routines - That is because possible mechanisms for shared libraries in machines that do not support virtual memory are limited). Unlike MacOS, however, it tends to keep binaries together in memory and doesn't scatter them all over the place.

@hippietrail: I don't think any systems used a single 68000 with any kind of MMU that could trigger non-fatal page faults, though some used a pair of 68000 CPUs, one of which was devoted to the task of handling not-fatal page faults in code running on the other.  The CPU which attempted to access the non-loaded page would observe, on potentially thousands of consecutive cycles, that a memory operation wasn't yet completed, and each time that happened it would postpone whatever it was doing for another cycle, oblivious to the fact that another CPU was shuffling data around.

Sure there's such a thing as a "binary" file--they're just not executable.  Many file formats have binary data in the data fork and either no resource fork or a resource fork which is used for ancillary information which could be useful for programs that understand it, or ignored by any that didn't.  A program that generates bitmap files compatible with other programs, for example, might include program-specific information about settings like snap grid, brush selection, etc.

@supercat Now, that's nitpicking on terminology. A MacOS application's internal structure is definitely not what most people would expect from a "binary file".

@tofro: Normal systems have binary executables and binary data files.  Executable files on classic Mac OS are not what most people would view as "normal binary files", but many programs use rather ordinaryish binary files to store data.

I think "binary file" is often used ambiguously which is why I specifically used "binary executable". Sometimes it means any file that's not text, sometimes it means any proprietary file format, sometimes it means executable. As for "most people" I'll wait to see the survey results. The bigger surprise for me is they can't be executed!?

I kept hunting and found the answer.
Executable code is stored in the resource fork in the CODE resource. (Possibly also in the data fork equivalent .rsrc resource files?)
From Wikipedia:

Some files have only a resource fork. One example is a font file in
the classic Mac OS. Another example is a Classic 68k application,
where even the executable code is contained in resources of type
'CODE'. Later PowerPC binaries stored the executable code in the data
fork.

And put more clearly in "About the Segment Manager" from GrapefruitIsAwesome's link in the comment below.

Your application’s executable code is stored in its resource fork as
one or more resources of type 'CODE'. These code resources are known
as segments because the division of routines into code resources is
controlled by segmentation directives you provide to your development
system.

I would still like to know more about it. For instance does the CODE resource have an internal format or does it rely on other resources to provide thinks like relocation and debugging information?

I think you'd be interested in the Segment Manager

Voted down because executable code isn't stored in the resource fork? Or because it's not in the CODE resource?

Voted down because you extend your question in the first simple version of the answer. Now it has more, I'd like to suggest to remove the additional question, though.

Please see Mac OS Runtime Architectures, specifically chapter 10,
Classic 68K Runtime Architecture.
